# Cannot install Web Developer Tools (WTP's JSP editor) on Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, flash-builder, eclipse-wtp

Why can't I install Web Developer Tools on Flash Builder 4.5? It always blows up one and the same error:

Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Structured Source XML Model 1.1.504.v201104070043 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.504.v201104070043)
    Structured Source XML Model 1.1.500.v2010052716a18 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.500.v201005271618)
    Structured Source XML Model 1.1.503.v201102102045 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.503.v201102102045)
    Structured Source XML Model 1.1.600.v201104251227 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.600.v201104251227)
    Structured Source XML Model 1.1.501.v201007151827 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.501.v201007151827)
    Structured Source XML Model 1.1.502.v201009010342 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.502.v201009010342)

Anyone else experiencing this issue. How can I overcome it? I thought that Eclipse manages dependencies automatically and pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're better to install Eclipse Java EE edition first and then install Flash Builder as a plugin - that's what my team has done using Eclipse 3.6 (we will try Eclipse 3.7 soon).  It's not clear from your question which version of Eclipse you are trying to use.